# When creating PNG in R, the legend is cut off

Tags: r, png, legend

I wrote some R code 4 years ago and haven't use R since.  I am struggling to get this working again:

```
radio_count = data[c("a","ac","an","bn","g")]

# Create a new PNG file
png(filename=png_file, width=850, height=600, bg="white") #,antialias="cleartype")

# Expand right side of clipping rect to make room for the legend
par(xpd=T, mar=par()$mar+c(5,0,0,5),las=3)

# actually plot the bar graphs, with title
barplot( t(radio_count), main=gr_title, ylab="# of clients",col=barcolors,names.arg=data[,1],ylim=c(0,150) )

legend(36.5,100,chartlegend,cex=0.8,fill=barcolors)
grid(nx= 0, ny = NULL, col="gray60",equilogs = TRUE) 

dev.off()
```

With 850x600, the legend is slightly clipped - meaning it only shows about 80% of the legend with the right most portion being cut off.

I need to use 1920x1080 now and the legend is not on the PNG at all.

What do I need to adjust to get the legend on the screen?

Comment: Margins, padding, or whatever relevant part of the box model. See `?par` for options; in this case, it looks like you need to mess with how you're setting `mar`. Default is `c("bottom" = 5, "left" = 4, "top" = 4, "right" = 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
barplot( t(radio_count), main=gr_title, ylab="# of clients", col=barcolors,
             cex.main=2.2, cex.names=1.65, cex.axis=1.65, cex.lab=1.4, 
             names.arg=data[,1], ylim=c(0,150) )
```

Also note that `ylim=c(0,150)` tells R to make the Y axis range from 0 to 150.